# Сумма значений из div одного класса для каждого родителя

Tags: javascript

Прошу помощи! Не получается вывести в результат (.result) суму значений (div.num) в каждом родителе (.sumAll)

```js
$(".summAll").click(function(){
var sum = 0.0;
$('.num').each(function()
{
    sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
});
$(this).find('.result').val(sum); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summAll">
<div class="num">1.25</div>
<div class="num">0.25</div>
<div class="num">3.00</div>
RESULT:
<input class="result">
</div>
<div class="summAll">
<div class="num">1.25</div>
<div class="num">0.25</div>
RESULT:
<input class="result">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".summAll").click(function() {
    let sum = 0.0;
    $(this).find('.num').each(function() {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^  
        sum += parseFloat($(this).html());
    });
    
    $(this).find('.result').val(sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="summAll">
  <div class="num">1.25</div>
  <div class="num">0.25</div>
  <div class="num">3.00</div>
  RESULT:
  <input class="result">
</div>
<div class="summAll">
  <div class="num">1.25</div>
  <div class="num">0.25</div>
  RESULT:
  <input class="result">
</div>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!) Вы спасли мне долгие часы мучений)